# What does "motatte" mean?

Tags: translation, words, parsing

> もう学校始まってから二週間もたってるよ

Please verify because I've seen in some dictionaries it's already an obsolete word, it means mota-"having done"

Some dictionaries don't have a word mota so I can't see the conjugations on this one.

Answer (score 12):

「たって」 is from the verb 経つ{たつ}, meaning "to pass (time)". It's usually not written in kanji.

も is a particle attached to 二週間, and when attached to a counter it means the speaker believes that that amount is a lot.

> もう学校始まってから二週間も経ってるよ
>   It's already been two weeks since school started!

Answer (score 7):

You are parsing it incorrectly: 二週間もたってる is 二週間も + たって（い）る.

- も is sense 一・④ in 大辞林

  > **も**
  >   **一** (係助)
  >   [...]
  >   ④ 極端な物事を指定し、強調する。…さえも。「聞いたこと–ない話」「太っ腹の社長–、今度はまいったようだ」

  and is for emphasis.
- たって is the te-form of 経つ (as in 時間がたつ "time passes")